# For loop in the column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having trouble with loops in a column.
My goal is to start another function if any cell in the column B has a value.

Here my code that I tried to readapt thanks to the previous answers.

```
  let startRow = 2;
  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  let numRows = lastRow  - startRow;
  let rng = sheet.getRange(2,2).getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++){
    
   let cell = rng[i];

    if (cell !== '') {     
      
      //otherfunction();      
      
    }
  }
```

**The problem is that the other function doesn't start**

What I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: How often do you run the first function?  The second function can on run if it's called by the first function because there is no trigger for what you want.

Comment: I'm trying it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

**Issue 1:**

- `getRange(2,2)` specifies only a single cell (**B2**) but because you use `getValues` you get a 2D array in the form `[[x]]`.

Therefore when you call `rng[i]` you get something like `[x]` which is, again, an array. Therefore, `cell !== ''` will always be `false`.

**Issue 2:**

It seems you want to iterate over column `B` but you in your code you only consider a single cell, therefore the `for` loop is not used and in fact `rng` has only one row (as I explained before).

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let values = sheet.getRange('B2:B'+sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    
   let cell = values[i];

   if (cell !== '') {     
      
      //otherfunction();      
      
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Thanks for the clear explanation. I'm trying to learn

Comment: I'm having a problem, when the column B is empty the other function starts and I receive this error `Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1`

Comment: I think I solved it, I have another if and I had put your code out of the first block. Now it's working fine. Excuse me.